# Using CopyFeatures_management without copying source GDB domains to 'in_memory' workspace?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, domains, in-memory

I know it's probably the opposite of what would generally be desirable, but I am trying to temporarily copy a Feature Class from a File GDB with Domains into a `in_memory` intermediate FC without maintaining the source Domains.

I cannot prove this because I don't know how (where) to look for the in-memory FC I produce, but when I do

```
temp_folder = r'in_memory'
arcpy.arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(temp_folder, 'temp'))
```

,I think I not only copy the entire source FC into the `in_memory` workspace, but also the source FileGDB's Domains.

Can someone confirm this behaviour? Is there a way to avoid this using the same tool (`CopyFeatures_management`) or (only if it's not possible) a similar tool?

I would like to keep using `in_memory` for my intermediate file, rather than create physical intermediate files because:

1. I would have to delete them
2. I would have to properly check for errors within my script, handle them in order to delete intermediate files before they reach the 'delete' part of the script
3. `in_memory` is faster because it uses RAM (is this true?)

I tried deleting the domains, but the code below seems to make ArcGIS crash all the time (imagine `domains` comes from something like `arcpy.ListDomains`)...

```
for d in domains:
    arcpy.DeleteDomain_management(temp_folder, d)
```

Comment: You can test what it does with domains by copying to `in_memory` then copying out again into a new geodatabase (that has no domains) and then just check whether it's included the domains.

Comment: It is exactly why I am asking this. The output is processed and put in a newly created FileGDB (i.e. without Domains), but when it is populated with the temporary FC, it populates with all the Domains.

Comment: An in_memory workspace resembles a file geodatabase but is not one.

Comment: If it didn't copy the domains, what would be the expected behavior if you had a domain on an integer field with a string description? In deleting the domains, are you accessing by name: `[d.name for d in arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [@PolyGeo's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213473/19311) script as basis, you can create an `in_memory` feature class that does not carry the domain information, it's just a bit of work:

```py
desc = arcpy.Describe("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC")
shape = desc.shapeType
spatref = desc.spatialReference

# create in_memory FC with the same spatial characteristics
temp = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "testFC", shape,
                                           spatial_reference=spatref)
fields = []
for field in arcpy.ListFields("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC"):
    if field.type.upper() not in ["OID", "GEOMETRY"]:
        fields.append(field.name)
        # Now add the attribute characteristics
        arcpy.AddField_management(temp, field.baseName, field.type, field.precision,
                                  field.scale, field.length, field.aliasName,
                                  field.isNullable, field.required)    

# And populate with attribute information
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC", fields) as sCursor:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(temp, fields) as iCursor:
        for row in sCursor:                
            iCursor.insertRow(row)    

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("in_memory/testFC", "C:/Temp/test2.gdb/testFC")
```

Probably going to be a fair bit slower. Delete domains after the fact with the following:

```py
for domain in arcpy.da.ListDomains(workspace):
   arcpy.DeleteDomain_management(workspace, domain.name)
```

Note:
During creation of the `in_memory` feature class, you **can't** use the input feature class as a template, as that will also carry the domain information (as it should)!

Answer (score 6):

When you copy a feature class to an in_memory workspace then all that I would have expected you to be copying is a feature class.

However, when I ran the test below it created output that indicates that the domains associated with a feature class are copied into the in_memory workspace, and if that in_memory feature class is copied out to a new file geodatabase then the domain is re-created in that new file geodatabase.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/Temp","test")
arcpy.CreateTable_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb","testTable","","")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testTable","txtField","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testTable","txtValue","TEXT")
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testTable",["txtField","txtValue"])
cursor.insertRow(("test1", "long text about test 1"))
del cursor
arcpy.TableToDomain_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testTable","txtField","txtValue","C:/Temp/test.gdb","testDomain","Test Domain","APPEND")
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains("C:/Temp/test.gdb")
print "Domains in original:"
for domain in domains:
    print domain.name
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC","0 0","0 1","1","1","2","2","","NO_LABELS", "DEFAULT","POLYGON")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC","txtField","TEXT","","","","","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","testDomain")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC","txtField",""""test" + str( !OID! )""","PYTHON")
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/Temp","test2")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC","in_memory/testFC")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("in_memory/testFC","C:/Temp/test2.gdb/testFC")
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains("C:/Temp/test2.gdb")
print "Domains in new file geodatabase:"
for domain in domains:
    print domain.name
```

The output from the above was:

```
>>> 
Domains in original:
testDomain
Domains in new file geodatabase:
testDomain
>>>
```

Comment: It appears (from OP's comment) that the domains are being copied through the in_memory into an output geodatabase.  There may be a bit more to it.

Comment: I know this. I also know that the 'in_memory' workspace is a FileGDB itself, and I am wondering if when I do "CopyFeatures", the 'in_memory''s GDB itself changes its properties, inheriting the Domains from the source GDB from where the FC is copied from. Is that possible?

Comment: It should be easy to test whether a feature class copied into an in_memory workspace and out again to a new file geodatabase creates domains there.

Comment: I think it does create domains, and I am asking how to avoid this (if possible). I will come back to my script and update my question with the tool I am using to push the 'in_memory' temporary FC to the final GDB to let others replicate this behaviour. Meanwhile thanks for the replies.